# Spring Boot Admin Client not registering an application

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have setup a SpringBootAdmin server, and trying to register an application with SpringBootAdmin client. It does not seem to be registering. 
Do I neccesarily have to register with Eureka? 
How do I debug?

Configuration on adminserver
build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server-ui')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=Boot-Admin
server.port=8093
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin    
logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin.client=DEBUG
logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin=DEBUG
```

App is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAdminServer
public class AdminApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

On the client side, 
build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8091
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8093
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
spring.boot.admin.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.password=admin
logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin.client=DEBUG
```

Code is

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SBACApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SBACApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

According to all the Stackoverflow articles and tutorials, this should be adequate. 
Even though logging is set on the client side, there seems to be no log-line starting with d.c....

What could I be missing
Any additional knowledge on how to debug this may help.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using spring boot admin 2.0 the the client url property would be

```
spring.boot.admin.client.url: http://localhost:8093
```

I would check to see what version you are using and then double check the property names.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 2.x.x version client url property is different that Spring Boot 1.x.x

```
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.url= http://localhost:8093
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
```

make sure you have other two properties. in my case i was missing auto registration property